# Using property in PHP function

Tags: php, date, date-format

I am looping trough a JSON file with

```
foreach ($json->response as $value) {
    echo date_format($value->arrival->scheduled_time, "H:i:s");
```

But the `date_format` PHP function doesn't work with `$value->arrival->scheduled_time`. What am I missing? `$value->arrival->scheduled_time` contains a date. For example `2020-12-27T19:55:00.000`

Comment: Sorry, a date. For example 2020-12-27T19:55:00.000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`date_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) expects parameter one to be a [`DateTime` object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). You are giving it a string. Assuming that string is in a valid datetime format, you need to ctreate a `DateTime` object *first* and then call `date_format()`.

```
foreach ($json->response as $value) {
    $datetime = date_create($value->arrival->scheduled_time);
    echo date_format($datetime , "H:i:s");
```

or in OOP:

```
foreach ($json->response as $value) {
    $datetime = new DateTime($value->arrival->scheduled_time);
    echo $datetime->format("H:i:s");
```